# File and Folder Sync Application .net C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am developing a .Net 4.0 C# Windows Service based (Dropbox like ) application which runs continuously and keeps a watch on a specific folder for content and updates and notify the changes onto the Database and similar clients application will be installed on other machines as well which will perform suitable updates to the same folder in their hosting machines. I have developed the whole application with multiple threads and recursion calls which will keep on performing  and notifying the changes through-out. The application runs well for 3 hrs after 3 hrs it throws in a stack-overflow exception and crashes.

To be more specific I have 9 threads and some of them do the following jobs

1) threadFSWToDB - write any file changes(add,rename,delete) to DB.

2) threadDBToUploadLogList - creates a folder on the server where the other clients will download file from.

3) threadDoUpload - will upload file on the web server.

4) threadDBToDownloadList - will upload a list of changes to be performed by polling DB.

my question is, is this the feasible solution or do I need to re-consider my design for the whole app. If yes what would be the best way to perform the above tasks (sequential or parallel). And what is the most basic approach for performing the tasks which are never ending and continuous in nature like this one.

My Code is as below, I don't know how much to put in so that it could make the matter clear

```
Thread threadFSWToDB = new Thread(() => WriteFSWLogListToDatabase());


private static void WriteFSWLogListToDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var objEntities = new ShareBoxEntities()) // EF class instantiation
            {
// this DB class constructor call later on throws stack overflow exception not necessarily from this method
                var objConnector = new DBConnector(objEntities); 
                var objConnector = new DBConnector();
                List<string> directories = objConnector.GetAllSharedDirectoryRelativePaths();
                if (FSWLogList != null && FSWLogList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= FSWLogList.Count - 1; i++)
                    {

            // some file changes being written to Database
                            FSWLogList[i].SavedInDB = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
    // write to event log and mail to administrator
        }
        finally
        {
            if (FSWLogList != null && FSWLogList.Count > 0)
            {
                FSWLogList.RemoveAll(item => item.SavedInDB == true);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            WriteFSWLogListToDatabase();
        }
    }
```

if recursion is the main reason then why the application runs fine for some times a day or two and then starts exhibiting the above mentioned behaviour

Comment: If you are creating threads manually, you may want to reconsider. Have you taken a look at the Parallel Task Library? If not, you really should. This should get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx

Comment: Not sure how we can really help without seeing any code. Do you know where the Exception is occurring? That should help you find where the trouble is. Sounds like you have an endlessly recursing call somewhere that is slowly recursing and never unwinding, so eventually the stack is exhausted.

Comment: @TimothyP Thanks for your valuable comments, more than the parallel execution, its about identifying the points where the parallel execution can take place, for which I may use the said link.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I forgot to mention, its while opening the EF connection that it throws the error and its not definite at what point it throws the error, its just when the DB connection object is about to be instantiated it throws error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their valuable time.

I have found out the solution to my problem, the recursive function calls have been replaced with a **while(true) //loop** 
still being called on the respective threads
This ensure that my function which monitors the folder doesn't complete its execution while a try and catch ensured it goes on even after an exception. The problem that I faced while using the **while(true)** was any resource used in a function was to be made available for the other functions running on separate thread, that was handled by calling the thread.sleep for a specific period. It may not be a universal solution to a similar problem but it fitted my requirement, so I would like others to just watch out before implementing the stated solution in a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the details, but a stack overflow error normally means that you're going too deep into your recursion

simple example

```
public void ThrowStackOverflow()
{
    ThrowStackOverflow()
}
```

Will always throw a stack overflow because there's no exit to the recursion.  the call stack just gets deeper and deeper until there's no room.

I suspect that your program has a similar issue of self-referential-ism.

If you have a recursive call that can potentially get too deep before winding back up, you risk a stack overflow.

OR if you thread creates itself without terminating, or maybe even if you just keep creating new threads without ever cleaning them up, something will inevitably give.

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like you are getting thread happy.    For DB you have BeginExecuteNonQuery for asynch db without a thread.  To get notifications from the DB you have Query Notifications.   For files you have FileSystemWatcher.   I would just use a BackGroundWorker to upload and download files.  If you are uploading / downloading to one server then preforming files in parallel is not going to help as you are most likely limited by bandwidth.